# How do I Make Adobe Reader the default owner of PDF files on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-reader, regedit

How to Make Adobe Reader the default owner of PDF files on Windows 10 via automatic procedure?

It can not be simply changed via registry change because of the Hash value in HCU.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.pdf\UserChoice]
"Hash"="k56kO7cBd6o="
"ProgId"="AcroRd32.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

Make file pdf_default.bat
This makes some registry changes to appear AcroRd32.exe to be between default programs and call .vbs file.

===pdf_default.bat===

```
@echo off
cls
echo   --==**##  Adobe Reader between default programs  ##**==--
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\CommonFiles\Usage\Reader 10" /v OptIn /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\AcroRd32.exe\shell\open\command /ve /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe\" \"%%1\"" /f >nul
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AcroRd32.pdf\shell\open\command /ve /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe\" \"%%1\"" /f >nul
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications /v "AcroRd32" /d "Software\AcroRd32\Capabilities" /f >nul
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AcroRd32\Capabilities /v "ApplicationDescription" /d "AcroRd32 is default program for PDF files." /f >nul
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AcroRd32\Capabilities /v "ApplicationName" /d "AcroRd32" /f >nul
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AcroRd32\Capabilities\FileAssociations /v ".pdf" /d "AcroRd32.pdf" /f >nul
cscript //NoLogo conf\IEdefault_PDFdefault.vbs
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
```

Now you can make PDF to open with AcroRd32.exe via GUI.
Thus we can avid breaking WIN10 Hash problem in registry 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.pdf\UserChoice]
"Hash"="k56kO7cBd6o="
"ProgId"="AcroRd32.pdf"

===PDFdefault.vbs===

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Open window to set Adobe Reader default program for PDF.
WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=AcroRd32"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys " "

Msgbox "Default program for PDF is AdobeReader."

WScript.Quit
```